# Using Fancybox (jquery plugin) in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery, lightbox, fancybox

I'm trying to get a line of code in my ASP.net application (using Visual Studio) to appear in a Jquery "Fancybox" window.  I know how to do this with a regular href link.  However, I'm confused on how to set this up using a dynamically generated one.

Here's my line of code that I would like to call Jquery:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hypPrint" style="margin-left: 5px;" CssClass="btn3" runat="server" Text="View/Print" CausesValidation="false" />
```

If I go into my CS file and look up hypPrint, here's what it's defined as:
    (e.Row.FindControl("hypPrint") as HyperLink).NavigateUrl = "PrintTicket.aspx?ticketid=" + id;

Basically I have to have this hyperlink call a defined ID for fancybox, called in the Head.  I would appreciate any help any ASP.Net experts can provide me!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. Do you need help wiring up the click event?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The quick and dirty way to do this would be to use the 'class' attribute as the selector for the fancybox plugin:

```
$('.btn3').fancybox();
```

Honestly, though, I'd make a more descriptive class and use that instead, but that debate belongs somewhere else. This should do the trick for you.